# TypeError: hog() got an unexpected keyword argument 'visualise'

Tags: python, opencv, typeerror, vehicle-routing

TypeError: hog() got an unexpected keyword argument'visualise'

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-24a971cd17ef> in <module>
     36 notcar = mpimg.imread(notcars[10])
     37 #plot_row2(car, notcar, 'Car', 'Not Car')
---> 38 car_features = single_img_features(car, color_space=color_space,
     39                                    spatial_size=spatial_size, hist_bins=hist_bins,
     40                                    orient=orient, pix_per_cell=pix_per_cell,

<ipython-input-20-9e1ff462ce4f> in single_img_features(img, color_space, spatial_size, hist_bins, orient, pix_per_cell, cell_per_block, hog_channel, spatial_feat, hist_feat, hog_feat)
    108             hog_features = []
    109             for channel in range(feature_image.shape[2]):
--> 110                 hog_features.extend(get_hog_features(feature_image[:,:,channel], 
    111                                     orient, pix_per_cell, cell_per_block,
    112                                     vis=False, feature_vec=True))      

<ipython-input-20-9e1ff462ce4f> in get_hog_features(img, orient, pix_per_cell, cell_per_block, vis, feature_vec)
     44     # Otherwise call with one output
     45     else:
---> 46         features = hog(img, orientations=orient, 
     47                        pixels_per_cell=(pix_per_cell, pix_per_cell),
     48                        cells_per_block=(cell_per_block, cell_per_block),

TypeError: hog() got an unexpected keyword argument 'visualise'
```

TypeError: hog() got an unexpected keyword argument'visualise'

Comment: welcome. please take the [tour] and review [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0):

you can try to replace 'visualise' to 'visualize'.